# How to customize horizontal jQuery-mobile radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, radio-button

Our client need a custom design radio button style for the jQuery-mobile. Actually it's very similar to default jQuery-mobile radio button design in horizontal mode. For example jQuery-mobile define the horizontal radio button as

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>I like to buy and wear trendy must-haves</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-2">2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-3">3</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-4">4</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-5" value="choice-5"  />
    <label for="radio-choice-5">5</label>
</fieldset>
```

Additionally our client wants to display the default radio button below the `lablel`. For example following image [image: custom horizontal radio button]

I would like to know does jQuery-mobile allow us to display the default radio buttons ? If so can you give an example ?

Or should we need to customize this ?

Comment: it should be possible using css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

First thing, it can't be done through the jQM configuration. This must be created manually through a jquery (like any other jQM widget, including fieldset).

I have created an working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/779Kn/

Your only need to do one more thing, I didn't want to bother with a custom images so I am using images created for my other example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13634738/1848600

Here's an javascript needed:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){     
    $('<div>').addClass('checkBox').appendTo('fieldset div div.ui-radio label');
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){        
        ($(this).is(':checked')) ? $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('checked') : $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('not-checked');
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.ui-radio', function(){      
        $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){  
            $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('not-checked').removeClass('checked');
        }); 
        
        if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')){
           $(this).find('label div.checkBox').removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked'); 
           $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked' , false);
        } else {
           $(this).find('label div.checkBox').removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');             
           $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked' , true);
        }        
    });  
});
```

Here's css:

```
.checkBox{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 3px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.not-checked, .checked {
    background-image: url("http://www.fajrunt.org/icons-18-white.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.not-checked {
    background-position: -18px 0;       
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
}

.checked {
    background-position: -720px 0;    
    background-color:#6294bc;
}
```

If you can wait few hours I will update a picture, I can't do it from my current location.

## Final notes

If you want to find more about how to customize jQuery Mobile page and widgets then take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**. It comes with a lot of working examples, including why is !important necessary for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: That's exactly what I want thanks a lot mac and Ofcourse I can till your next update. Could please clarify me the last question which I figure it out from your demo. Instead of define the '.not-checked, .checked' css can I use the current jquery mobile provided sprite image with different background colour to the radio buttons so we can avoid adding more css ?

Comment: Yes you can use them easily. I will soon change my example to accommodate original jQM images.

Comment: I just noticed on your demo when I click on the label eg (1,2,3,4,5) radio button is not showing the checked icon in the circle and even if I click on the radio button it's not working. If I need check that icon I need to click next option accurately in the circle and choose the former option. I'm very sorry to bother you again because I'm not good at JS.

Comment: Now it works, I fixed it 10 minutes ago. Answer code example is also fixed.

Comment: Updated with a original jQM img.

Comment: Contact me through my personal email if you need any more help.

Comment: I apologies to dig this up again. Above your updates are not working in actual devices and Mac desktop stimulators could you please look into this ASAP. I've created a sample page please test this page on actual devices http://www.apartmentslanka.com/ztest_calender/radio.html

Comment: Please visit the following post to see **Gajotres** latest update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643485/how-to-customize-horizontal-jquery-mobile-radio-buttons.

Answer (score 2):

No css or javascript necessary; it's a matter of which elements and classes you use, e.g:

```
<div id="test_content" class="ui-content" data-role="main" data-theme="b">    
    <fieldset class="ui-controlgroup ui-corner-all">
      <div class="ui-grid-b ui-controlgroup-controls" style="width: 560px;">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
          <input name="invoicing_filter_type" id="invoicing_filter_tobeinvoiced"
            value="1|4" type="radio" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="bottom">
          <label for="invoicing_filter_tobeinvoiced">To be invoiced</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <input name="invoicing_filter_type" id="invoicing_filter_pending" 
            value="9|5" type="radio" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="bottom">
          <label for="invoicing_filter_pending">Invoices pending</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <input name="invoicing_filter_type" id="invoicing_filter_tobereleased" 
            value="9|6" type="radio" data-mini="true" data-iconpos="bottom">
          <label for="invoicing_filter_tobereleased">Invoices to be released</label>
        </div>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
</div>
```

Note that data-role is NOT used here. Corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8bvK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

Using CSS

```
.myclass2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
.myclass {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    left: 13px;
    margin-top: 26px;
    padding-left: 22px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eREux/1/)**

Comment: ofcourse, but I copied your css and HTML code to my working file and it's not reading the default jquerymobile css.