# JQuery mobile customize horizontal radio buttons are not working in Actual Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-radio

Recently I asked a question on Stackoverflow that **How to customize horizontal jQuery-mobile radio buttons** you can also view the post from this link [How to customize horizontal jQuery-mobile radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643485/how-to-customize-horizontal-jquery-mobile-radio-buttons) . A developer very cursorily answered the question with very good JSFiddle example. According to his instruction I implemented the custom JQuery Mobile radio button and it's all working fine in desktop browsers.

However when I checked on actual devices (Galaxy S 2, IPhone 5, Mac simulators and Android simulators) and it's not working as like desktop browsers acts. I'm not sure what's wrong here but I can understand there is a small tweak I need to do to support for actual devices. I'm not good at JS therefore, could anyone please look into this ASAP.

Here is the Previous JSFiddle example done by **Gajotres** http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/779Kn/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){     
    $('<div>').addClass('checkBox').appendTo('fieldset div div.ui-radio label');
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){        
        ($(this).is(':checked')) ? $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('checked') : $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('not-checked');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.ui-radio', function(){      
        $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){  
            $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('not-checked').removeClass('checked');
        });

        if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')){
           $(this).find('label div.checkBox').removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked');
           $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked' , false);
        } else {
           $(this).find('label div.checkBox').removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');             
           $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked' , true);
        }        
    });   
});

.checkBox{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 3px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.not-checked, .checked {
    background-image: url("http://www.fajrunt.org/icons-18-white.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.not-checked {
    background-position: -18px 0;       
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
}

.checked {
    background-position: -720px 0;    
    background-color:#6294bc;
}
```

I created a separate link hope this will help you to quickly check on devices. http://www.apartmentslanka.com/ztest_calender/radio.html

***Stackoverflow FYI: I tried to continue from previous post but since the responsible developer unable to answer or check the last issue I created a new post.**

Answer (score 3):

You really need to be patient, I was on holiday :)

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/779Kn/20/

And this version should work on touch devices and desktop browsers alike: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/779Kn/21/

**Click** event was changed to **touchstart** event, and now it also works on mobile devices.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){     
    $('<div>').addClass('checkBox').appendTo('fieldset div div.ui-radio label');
    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){        
        ($(this).is(':checked')) ? $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('checked') : $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('not-checked');
    });

    $(document).on('touchstart', '.ui-radio', function(){      
        $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){  
            $(this).next().find(".checkBox").addClass('not-checked').removeClass('checked');
        }); 

        if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')){
           $(this).find('label div.checkBox').removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked'); 
           $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked' , false);
        } else {
           $(this).find('label div.checkBox').removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');             
           $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked' , true);
        }        
    });   
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! really appriceate your help mac and really sorry to bother you. This update won't work now in desktop browser right ? Is that meant to like that or can we define a both desktop and Mobile supported event ?

Comment: This version should work on touch devices and desktop browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/779Kn/21/

Comment: Thank you for this and during your reply I tried this event `$(document).on('touchstart click', '.ui-radio', function(e)` and it's working fine in both touch devices and desktop browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just one additional comment (in case someone happens upon this question in the future) - the newer versions of JQueryMobile provide the "vclick" event which is the same thing as looking for "touch start" on mobile devices, and "click" on desktop browsers.